# Atomicity of SQL UPDATE statement with WHERE clause in Derby

Tags: sql, concurrency, sql-update, derby, atomic

I'm writing a (Java) function, which will be run in multiple processes, that picks a random username from a Derby SQL database. I don't want more than one process at a time using the same username, so I want to add a "flag" column to act as a lock. I read [the documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop63.html) on transactions that says each statement is atomic, but I'm not 100% confident in my logic/knowledge of what that really entails.

My strategy is to first select a random username with this (say I have a table `usernames` with columns `username` and `flag`):

```
SELECT username FROM usernames WHERE flag='0' ORDER BY RANDOM() FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Then pass the username retrieved to this (via a prepared statement):

```
UPDATE usernames SET flag='1' WHERE username=? AND flag='0';
```

And save the return value (the count of rows updated). If 1 row was updated, carry on with the selected username. If no rows were updates, start over and try again.

Is this a reliable locking mechanism to ensure that no two processes end up with the same username? E.g. if two processes get the same username back from the `SELECT` statement, is it guaranteed that only one will get a result of 1 from the `UPDATE`? Or am I misunderstanding what it means for a statement to be atomic?

Comment: you shouldnt need to set a flag, what it sounds like you want to do is lock the record and the db should handle this for you. I'm not familiar with derby but from a quick google produceshttps://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/ref/rrefsqlj31783.html

Comment: @TI I do need to set the flag, as once the process gets a username it could be using it for 20+ seconds, and I still don't want another proc coming along 5s later and using it.

Comment: how would all other processes know to check the flag. sounds like a pita to implement and enforce that sort of logic. I think you may be confusing atomicity and concurrency. locks handle concurrency. transactions handle atomicity (units of work).

Comment: @TI All the processes are running the same function, so it's easy to implement. I want to make sure that I can't run into a situation where procA finds a row matching the where, procB finds the same row matching the where, procA does the update, and then procB does its update, and neither knows the other is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I would use something other than a boolean, e.g. the process id of the process currently using the name. That way it becomes easier to debug and release bogus flag=true locks resulting from a process crash.

Derby supports transactions which satisfy the ACID properties. A transaction can contain any number of statements. E.g.:

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false); // true by default

try {
  // execute select
  // execute update
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
  conn.rollback() // abort transaction and undo all effects
}
conn.commit();    // commit transaction, make changes visible
```

Note that the exact behavior is controlled by the [isolation level](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/devguide/index.html) set for the connection. The default is READ COMMITTED.

If you do it this way, there should be no need to test if the update was successful, as the transaction mechanism sets the necessary locks to ensure that the username you selected is not modified by others until the transactions ends.

Note that in your case the rollback may not be necessary, as only the update has visible effects that needs to be undone and the update statement itself is atomic.